# Разница между define и const

Tags: c++, c, синтаксис

В чем в C++ разница между #define и const? То есть какой из вариантов предпочтительнее и в какой ситуации, есть ли вообще разница?

Comment: Ответ на этот вопрос принципиально отличается в С и С++. Вы "просто так" указатели сразу два языка в тегах? Или вас действительно интересуют оба языка?

Comment: Меня интересуют оба языка, хотелось бы узнать в чем разница, потому что чаще встречала в C - define, а в С++ - const

Comment: В моем ответе по ссылке (дубликат) затрагивается тема того, почему в С используется именно `#define`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#define` - это макрос препроцессора, он просто выполняет замену строки текста на своё содержимой. До c++11 его имело смысл использовать для глобальных численных констант.

`const` - это квалификатор типа, говорящий, что переменная не должна меняться после инициализации. Но эта инициализация где-то должна произойти, и от константности можно вручную избавиться при помощи `const_cast`.

В c++11 был добавлен квалификатор `constexpr`, который указывает на то, что переменная может как-то изменяться только во время компиляции, но не во время выполнения. Детали зависят от версии стандарта. Теперь можно без проблем объявлять статические константы, в том числе сложных типов. Например:

```
namespace constants{
  static constexpr double g = 9.8;

  struct minus_fn_impl{
    template<class T> 
    T operator () (const T& lha, const T& rha){
       return lha - rha;
    }
  };

  static constexpr minus_fn_impl minus_fn;
}

...

double v = 5.3;
double r = constants::minus_fn(v, constants::g); // не нужно инициализировать функциональный объект, как в случае std::minus
```

Comment: Вопрос также помечен тегом [C]. В ответе ни слова не сказано о С.

Answer (score 6):

Конечно, есть. Хотя бы в том, что `const` дает возможность проверки типов. Компилятор знает, что такое `const`, и разбирается, на своем ли он месте. О `#define` знает только препроцессор.

Так что - всегда предпочтительнее `const`.

Comment: Главное, не ковыряться в памяти по адресу таких констант =)

Comment: Вопрос также содержит тег [C]. В языке С `const` не применим там, где требуется именно константа. Поэтому в С за исключением редких случаев - именно `#define`. Причем не "предпочтительнее", а "без вариантов".

Comment: @vp_arth,  думаю все еще хуже, чем вы имели в виду.  К сожалению тему закрыли и невозможно сделать ответ с кодом, но суть в том, что в С++ при изменении `const ...` по адресу *значение отрывается от адреса!!!*. Ага, `const int a = 10; const int *ap = &a; change_a(ap); printf("%d %d\n", a, *ap);` печатает **разные числа**. (Кстати, такая "шизофрения" только в крестах, в Си все "честно" -- значение константы изменяется)

Answer (score 1):

`#define` - это препроцессорная директива; препроцессор заменяет все эти макросы во время компиляции.

`const` переменные - это фактические переменные языка. 
Плюсы констант в проверке типов и т.п, как пример.

В целом, насколько я могу судить, в итоге получаем одно и то же. Разве что, у define'ов нету области видимости, а у констант есть.

Answer (score 1):

Разница вот в чём:
definы компилятор просто подставляет во время компиляции, т.е. пишешь такой код:
`#define NAME "Alex"
...
std::cout << NAME`
И когда ты запускаешь компиляцию, компилятор сначала преобразует это в:
`std::cout << "Alex"`
И только потом компилирует.
А вот, когда ты используешь const, создаётся обычная переменная, только её нельзя изменять, т.е. если тв попробуешь её изменить, компилятор выдаст ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Использовать #define только там, где нет возможности использовать const (constexpr в c++11). То есть, для определения констант #define уже достаточно давно использовать не рекомендуется.